Как сделать так, чтоб на отключенном объекте в юнити продолжал работать скрипт?
Делаю игру, где используется несколько камер, которые переключаются между собой, в этих камерах есть по две картинки с состоянием, мне нужно чтобы даже когда объект камеры выключается, скрипт, висящий на нем, продолжал работать.

У отключенного объекта скрипты не выполняются. Это не изменить.

Так не деактивируй весь объект, а только скрипт камеры на нём.

Создать пустой объект , поместить на него скрипт , который будет выполняться.
В этом объекте создать дочерний объект, который отвечает за визуал,например модельку персонажа. Когда нужно,вы отключаете дочерний объект с визуалом, при этом сам объект продолжит свою работу.
